# Why do we import scikit-learn with sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why is that we install the scikit-learn package with:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

but then import (modules from) the package in a script using the name `sklearn`, e.g.:

```
from sklearn import x
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`scikit-learn` isn't a valid identifier in python, so it can't be *that*.  I suppose that they could have named the package `scikit_learn`, but that's a lot to type so I suppose they just decided to shorten the package name for convenience.

Of course, if you're so inclined, you *can*:

```
import sklearn as scikit_learn
```

:-)

Comment: Because it'll parse as "scikit minus learn" -- IOW, it parses as 2 identifiers and an operator.

Comment: Being new to Python, can you elaborate why packages would appear to have two names at all?  Is there some terminology here, like "sklearn is the package name" and "scikit-learn" is the ______ name?"

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that there's an answer to this question :).  Ultimately, people name things the way that they want to.  The package authors are free to name it one way in documentation (e.g. the website) and then expose the package under a slightly different name (potentially they feel like it's more convenient to type).  Some packages also have very common abbreviations that are recommended in the documentation -- e.g. `import numpy as np` ... `np` certainly isn't the package name, but it's a very common shortcut that has been well adopted by the community.

Comment: Instead of supposing that they could have named the package ```scikit_learn```, did you ever suppose that they could have named it ```sklearn```?!